# How can ID of a custom-named register be displayed in the document (not terminal or log)?

Tags: registers

How to get a hold of ID of a register? I can see it with `\show` but can't use it (save and display) in the document itself.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \newdimen\dA
  \show\dA % OUTPUT: \dA=\dimen105
  % HOW TO DISPLAY 105
  %  (WHICH IS ID OF \dA REGISTER)?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information shown on the terminal by `\show` is always available in-document using `\meaning`

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \newdimen\dA
  at this point you could use\\
   \the\allocationnumber\\
   but after  \newcount\zzz  that will change but you can use\\
   \texttt{\meaning\dA.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But you should never need to know that number, that is rather the point of the allocation system.